# Google container engine / Kubernetes 1.1.1 - Service LoadBalancer not being created

Tags: google-cloud-platform, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have an existing Kubernetes cluster on Google Container Engine (running api version 1.0.7). When I created 2 service with type LoadBalancer, gke created the necessary forwarding rules to expose them. I changed one of the ip addresses to static and kept one as ephemeral.

I'm trying to migrate to a new cluster (api version 1.1.1) and have created my services however the forwarding rules have not been created. When i describe the services I see the following error:

> CreatingLoadBalancerFailed    Error creating load balancer (will retry): Failed to create load balancer for service development/my-service: error waiting for gce static IP address to be created: googleapi: Error 403: Quota 'STATIC_ADDRESSES' exceeded.  Limit: 1.0

I understand that there is a limit of one static ip on Google Cloud Platform, does this mean that I can now only have 1 service on GKE exposed to public internet? Or is there a way I can work around this?

I need at least 2 external addresses (only 1 is for production so the restriction of 1 static ip is not an issue for me)

Answer (score 4):

While your project is in free trial, you are subject to reduced usage quotas. The quota for static IPs during the trial period is 1.

With that said, if you need to test Google Cloud Platform beyond the limits allowed on the free trial, you can upgrade to a paid account. After upgrading your account static IP quota will be increased to 7. Moreover, any remaining amount of your initial $300 credit remains in your account. This credit expires after 60 days, when your free trial period would have originally ended.

Comment: The static ip quota isn't necessarily a problem as I was previously able to create Kubernetes services of type `LoadBalancer` and this would create public ephemeral ip addresses. However how do I upgrade to a paid account? I have already entered credit card details (but I do still have trial credit remaining) but the quota of 1 static ip remains. Thanks

Comment: Found the upgrade button on the quotas page

Comment: @toby I'm glad you have resolved your issue.